# Unaligned apk from unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

**TLDR**: Is it possible to build an unaligned apk from unity3d? (or unalign an already aligned apk)

I have to deliver an unsigned, unaligned apk to a third party that then signs it using their certificate.

Apparently it worked last year with no problems. But now it seems the apk built from unity is always aligned.

Tried ticking "development build" on and off to no avail. No other settings seems to pertain to building an unaligned apk.

[image]

I am using unity3 version 5.3.5f1 and unsigning the apk with

```
zip -d output.apk "META-INF*"
```

all insight is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't selecting the Unsigned( debug) alias for the key what you want ?

[image]

Comment: I thought so too. But didn't make a difference.